# Can TypeScript convert a generic enum type to a runtime string?

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-generics

I have the following enum and interfaces:

```
enum EventId {
  FOO = 'FOO',
  BAR = 'BAR',
}

interface EventIdOptionsMap {
  [EventId.FOO]: {
    fooOption: string;
  },
  [EventId.BAR]: {
    barOption: number;
  }
}

interface EventRequest<K extends EventId> {
  eventId: K;
  options: EventIdOptionsMap[K];
}
```

Now, I could create an object and get type safety like:

```
const blah: EventRequest<EventId.FOO> = {
  eventId: EventId.FOO,
  options: {
    fooOption: 'testing',
    bad: false, // this would fail
  }
}
```

I have to type the `EventId.FOO` bit twice. I was hoping I could create a utility function where I can only specify it once like:

```
function createEvent<K extends EventId>(
  eventId: K,
  options: EventIdOptionsMap[K]
): EventRequest<K> {
  return {
    eventId,
    options
  };
}
```

but I still have to specify it twice to make it work:

```
const event = createEvent<EventId.FOO>(EventId.FOO, {
  fooOption: 'testing'
});

// I can be SURE that `event` is implicity of type `EventRequest<EventId.FOO>`
```

However, I still have to specify the `enum` twice, once as a generic type, and once as an argument (for runtime).

Is there any way where I can only specify it once, either as a generic *or* as an argument, and still generate the type safety that I am after?

I feel like this *should* be possible because `enum`s are a weird kind of type, they do exist at runtime. So I feel like there *should* be a way of telling TypeScript "this type is an enum, so we should be able to use it at runtime" or something like that.

I hate having to specify things twice, I'm trying to reduce boilerplate because we'll be writing these objects a lot.

Is there an alternate way that I can achieve the same goal?

Comment: Generics are part of the type system, and JavaScript has no type system. Once the TypeScript is compiled into JavaScript, all type information is lost. As such, there's no way to get the generic type at runtime because at runtime it doesn't exist.

Comment: I know, however, Typescript does generate real objects for enums. So theoretically, typescript could figure this out at compile time? I was wondering if there was a way

Comment: The code in your example results in `EventRequest<EventId.FOO>` without supplying a generic type parameter (https://tsplay.dev/w2P9bm). What's the issue?

Comment: It does... how does that even work? I don't know, but I'll test it and get back to you

Comment: @jsejcksn you are correct, it never occurred to me to just remove the generic type parameter. I assumed it would have to be passed! I will answer my own question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the type parameter and TypeScript will figure it out:

```
const event = createEvent(EventId.FOO, {
  fooOption: 'testing'
});
```

See [here](https://tsplay.dev/w2P9bm)

Comment: See [the handbook documentation for generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html); specifically *type argument inference*